# $u$ loc. Lipschitz: prove $\sum_{i,j=1}^N \xi_i\xi_j \int_O u\partial_{x_i,x_j} \phi \ge C |\xi|^2\int_O \phi,$ for $\phi \in C^\infty_0, \phi \ge 0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis

Let $O \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ open. Let $u:O \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous locally Lipschitz function. If necessary, we may also assume that $u$ is $C^\infty(O)$.

How can we prove that there exists a constant $C$ such that
$$\sum_{i,j=1}^N \xi_i\xi_j \int_O u\partial^2_{x_i,x_j} \varphi \ge C |\xi|^2\int_O \varphi$$
holds for all $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^N$, $\varphi \in C^\infty_0(O)$, $\varphi \ge 0$?

Comment: Integration by parts seems to get me nowhere.

Comment: This inequality does not hold true, take $u = 0$. I would guess that the inequality holds if $u$ is strongly convex, since (if $u$ would be smooth) the left-hand side is an average of $\xi^\top \nabla^2 u \xi$, where $\nabla^2 u$ is the Hessian of $u$.

Comment: @gerw Actually, upon further reflection, I see I only need $C$ a constant, not necessarily positive.

Comment: Under your new assumptions, $O = (-1,1)$ and $u(x) = 1/(x-1)$ should be a counterexample. The regularity $u \in C^2(\bar O)$ should be sufficient for your claim.

Comment: @gerw I see. Do you have any idea how the proof should go?

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume $u \in C^2(\bar O)$. Using integration by parts, we find
$$\int_O u \, \partial^2_{x_i,x_j} \varphi = \int_O \partial^2_{x_i,x_j} u \, \varphi$$
(recall that $\varphi$ vanishes outside of a compact set).
Since $\partial^2_{x_i,x_j} \varphi$ is bounded in $L^\infty(O)$, we further find
$$\int_O u \, \partial^2_{x_i,x_j} \varphi = \int_O \partial^2_{x_i,x_j} u \, \varphi \ge - \|u\|_{C^2(\bar O)} \, \|\varphi\|_{L^1(O)}.$$
Now, the desired inequality (with $C < 0$) follows easily.